# WebVR Extension with Basic Application Example

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I am trying to use the WebVR extension with a basic application. Instead of a 3D model in VR, the below html renders a 2D model. The code is mostly boilerplate except for where I call the WebVR extension. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- vr.html -->
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <!-- The Viewer CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/style.min.css" type="text/css">

    <!-- Developer CSS -->
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
        }
        #MyViewerDiv {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #F0F8FF;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <!-- The Viewer will be instantiated here -->
    <div id="MyViewerDiv"></div>

    <!-- The Viewer JS -->
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Developer JS -->
    <script>
        var viewerApp;
        var options = {
            env: 'AutodeskProduction',
            // Here is the WebVR extension
            extensions: ['Autodesk.Viewing.WebVR'],
            getAccessToken: function(onGetAccessToken) {
                //
                // TODO: Replace static access token string below with call to fetch new token from your backend
                // Both values are provided by Forge's Authentication (OAuth) API.
                //
                // Example Forge's Authentication (OAuth) API return value:
                // {
                //    "access_token": "<YOUR_APPLICATION_TOKEN>",
                //    "token_type": "Bearer",
                //    "expires_in": 86400
                // }
                //
                var accessToken = {{ accessToken }};
                var expireTimeSeconds = 60 * 30;
                onGetAccessToken(accessToken, expireTimeSeconds);
            }

        };
        var documentId = {{ documentID }};
        // var config = {
            // extensions: ['Autodesk.Viewing.WebVR'],
            // experimental: ['webVR_orbitModel']
        // };
        Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(options, function(){
            viewerApp = new Autodesk.Viewing.ViewingApplication('MyViewerDiv');
            viewerApp.registerViewer(viewerApp.k3D, Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D);
            viewerApp.loadDocument(documentId, onDocumentLoadSuccess, onDocumentLoadFailure);
        });

        function onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {

            // We could still make use of Document.getSubItemsWithProperties()
            // However, when using a ViewingApplication, we have access to the **bubble** attribute,
            // which references the root node of a graph that wraps each object from the Manifest JSON.
            var viewables = viewerApp.bubble.search({'type':'geometry'});
            if (viewables.length === 0) {
                console.error('Document contains no viewables.');
                return;
            }

            // Choose any of the avialble viewables
            viewerApp.selectItem(viewables[0].data, onItemLoadSuccess, onItemLoadFail);
        }

        function onDocumentLoadFailure(viewerErrorCode) {
            console.error('onDocumentLoadFailure() - errorCode:' + viewerErrorCode);
        }

        function onItemLoadSuccess(viewer, item) {
            console.log('onItemLoadSuccess()!');
            console.log(viewer);
            console.log(item);

            // Congratulations! The viewer is now ready to be used.
            console.log('Viewers are equal: ' + (viewer === viewerApp.getCurrentViewer()));
        }

        function onItemLoadFail(errorCode) {
            console.error('onItemLoadFail() - errorCode:' + errorCode);
        }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Where {{ documentID }} is my urn and {{ accessToken }} is my token.

Comment: You can take a look at the blog post my colleague wrote: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/add-webvr-support-viewer. As Zhong mentioned VR for a 2D model is an unusual expectation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I don't think the WebVR extension works for 2D model, I just tried with a f2d file, and it's not working, what do you expect for 2D in VR?

I also suggest you to use the Viewer version at least 2.13, if you do not specify any version of viewer, it will use 2.12 by default as I tried. And if you check the viewer 2.12 code of WebVR extension at https://developer.api.autodesk.com/viewingservice/v1/viewers/viewer3D.js?v=2.12, you will see it does not use webvr-polyfill when your browser does not support WebVR natively. But, since from viewer 2.13, the following code is added to support webvr-polyfill, that makes your browser to support WebVR even it does not natively support WebVR yet.

```
// check if browser supports webVR1.1 natively, if not, load polyfill
avp.loadDependency('VRFrameData', 'webvr-polyfill.min.js', function() {})
```

Last, I have a simple running sample for WebVR at https://viewervr.herokuapp.com if you want to check the result, nothing more but just load the "'Autodesk.Viewing.WebVR" extension, if you run it on your mobile device, you will see the expected result.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Zhong. I'll check out your sample app and add the latest version number to my code. To be clear, I'm not trying to view 2D models in VR (though that's not unheard of). It's just that the above code only renders the model in 2D, without the ability to switch to 3D. Not sure why at the moment.

Comment: If you model contain 3D model, you can change the following code to select 3D viewerable:             // Choose any of the avialble viewables
            viewerApp.selectItem(viewables[0].data, onItemLoadSuccess, onItemLoadFail);